# Use TimePicker or DatePicker within Preferences Screen on Android

Tags: android, datepicker, timepicker, preferencescreen

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a Data and Time picker for and app I'm building. I can't seem to find a built in way to allow the user to set the date they quit. Is there an elegant way to implement one? I'll need to be able to pull the day, month, year, hour, and minute values in order to calculate milliseconds. Any advice on what's available to achieve this?

Answer (score 14):

For time/date picker within `PreferenceScreen`, you can invoke the dialog using `onPreferenceClickListener` (Preference). Use `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` or `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener` within `PreferenceActivity` to retrieve the selected date/time.

`SettingsActivity.java`

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        Preference btnDateFilter = (Preference) findPreference("btnDateFilter");
        btnDateFilter.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                showDateDialog();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        Log.i("dasd","year "+i+" month "+i2+" day "+i3);
    }

    private void showDateDialog(){
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        new DatePickerDialog(this,this, year, month, day).show();

    }
}
```

`preference.xml`

```
<Preference
    android:key="btnDateFilter"
    android:summary="Reschedule using current setting"
    android:title="Reschedule" />
```